# Bash script to wait for gnome-terminal to finish before continuing script, only works for first instance of script

Tags: bash, expect, gnome-terminal

I have a bash script that opens a new gnome terminal with two tabs that runs more scripts. After the scripts in the two tabs finishes, the main script in the parent terminal continues to run.

When I run multiple instances of this bash script, it no longer waits for the additional gnome-terminals to finish before continuing the parent terminal script.

How do I fix it so that the additional instances of the script runs just like the first one?

Here is the bash script that I'm running. I run additional instances of this by typing `sh scriptname.sh` in a new terminal.

```
    gnome-terminal --tab --command="expect launchneuron.exp" --tab --command="expect launchmpj.exp"
echo "Simulation Complete"
echo "Plotting Results"
expect -c "
set timeout -1
spawn ssh $username@server
expect \"password\"
send \"$password\r\"
expect \"$ \"
send \"qsub -I -q abc -A lc_tb -l nodes=1 -l walltime=24:00:00 -d .\r\"
expect \"$ \"   
send \"sh plotgraph.sh\r\" 
expect \"$ \" 
send \"exit\r\"
"
```

Comment: Can you show the script - how do you "wait"? How do you run "multiple instances"? Not enough information here to reproduce what you describe.

Comment: I added the extra info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
date
bash -c "sleep 7" &
bash -c "sleep 5" &
wait
date
```

As you can see while running this script, **both** sleep **commands will run in parallel**, but **main thread stalls**, while they are running.

```
Sat. Jule 27 01:11:49 2013
Sat. Jule 27 01:11:56 2013
```

Replace `sleep 7` with `expect launchneuron.exp`

and `sleep 5` with `expect launchmpj.exp`

and add your plot commands after calling `"wait"`:

```
echo "Simulation Complete"
...(your code to plot results)
```

Comment: This doesn't work when one of the commands relinquishes control to the bash right away-- something like `gnome-terminal` or `nautilus`.